# How do I allow users to connect to private IP through static public IP address?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, virtual-machine, vpn

Before ignoring, please just read through. None of the previously asked questions helped.

I have 3 VMs set up in a local data center that are running the following OS:

- VM1: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9
- VM1: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9
- VM1: Ubuntu 20.04

I got these 3 VMs as part of the cheapest plan for IaaS web hosting, and I'm having issues when trying to actually host a website.

The 3 VMs have private IPs - 10.9.87.123, 10.9.87.456, and 10.9.87.789 - that I can access/SSH into only if connected to the data center's VPN. The public IP on all 3 VMs is 1.2.3.4.

Whenever I try to ping or access the public IP, the connection gets timed out - with or without the VPN. I am able to point my domain to any one of the private IPs, and access that domain with no issues if connected to the VPN.

I don't have access to any router or any actual hardware. I'm using windows cmd to run all commands via ssh, and would really love if someone could help out. The data center support team hasn't responded to me in the past 3 days, which is why I've come here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will _really_ need to get a reply from the data center admins regarding this. It's not a configuration issue from your side – if the VMs weren't made to be accessible externally then they literally aren't accessible externally. (Though your "IaaS" description kind of makes it sound like the data center expects you to additionally buy a different kind of VM – one VM with public IP address for frontend, VMs with private IPs for various backend services – or to use their managed proxy/load-balancer service.)

Comment: If you provided details on the service provider we could look at their documentation for you.  If they haven't responded in 3 days maybe they are just reselling service.